BMX no wobble warped back tire
I have 2021 HuTCh 911 BMX. I can feel the brake pads favour the one side rim confirming it's warped, but it's not affecting my riding or making the ride not smooth.
I can't get it fixed for a week.  Is there anything I should avoid  while the tires like that?
BMX is visually warped but no crack or spokes are broken and it doesn't wobble at high or low speeds  but when I look behind or walk it I can see it.


Please clarify - is your rim warped, or is it your tyre which is not straight on the rim ?   Have you squeezed every pair of spokes looking for a loose/broken one?   Have you tried spinning the wheel to see if it is true?

Some terminology to aid in clarity.


A wheel is the combination of the hub, spokes and rim.
A tire only refers to the part of the bike that makes contact with the ground.
When the wheel is spun, if the rim does not spin straight (it moves right and left as it spins), it is out of true.
If the wheel moves up and down as it spins, then it is out of round.

It sounds like your wheel is out of true and is making contact with one brake pad.
In many cases you can true a wheel by adjusting spoke tension.
If the wheel is only a little out of true, it may be possible to adjust the brake so that the wheel spins between the pads without contacting either pad.
If the rim is making mild contact with the brake pad, it's OK to ride.
